# The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. - Moving rows with button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first question here, so apologies for any errors in posting. I have found many related questions, but nothing that solved my problem. I have the code below in a spreadsheet that is supposed to move selected rows (the user enters the first row to archive and the last row to archive) to an archive sheet. I am getting this error:

> The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid.

related to this line:

```
s.getRange(rowStart, 1, numR, 9).moveTo(target);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
function onButton() {

// assumes source data in sheet named Orders

// target sheet of move to named Archived

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var s = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");

var cellStart = s.getRange(11,2);

var cellEnd = s.getRange(12,2);

var rowStart = cellStart.getValue();

var numR = cellEnd.getValue() - cellStart.getValue() + 1;

var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archived");

var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, numR);

s.getRange(rowStart, 1, numR, 9).moveTo(target);

s.deleteRows(rowStart, numRows);

}
```

Comment: The question doesn't have enough details. Please add the values of B11 and B12.

Comment: And although In your script, it seems that ``numRows`` is not declared, also can you confirm it?

Comment: Thanks for checking on this! @Rubén The cells with the values are actually K2 and L2, did I reverse those? For the test, the value of K2 is "2" and L2 is "3". As for numRows, I noticed that error after posting and have since changed it to numR.

Comment: `getRange(row,col)`, `getRange(11,2)`  is B11. The first value is the row and the second column. You can also use `getRange("K2")` instead.

Comment: Rubén and @James, I just checked on that myself and saw that I had reversed those. Thank you! I had a new problem. On the Archived sheet, the rows were moving offset by one column (i.e. A-I is moving to B-J). I realized I had misused getRange again. It's all working now. Thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone reading this later on, the commenters gave me the clues I needed to fix it, here is the now-working code:

```
function onButton() {

// assumes source data in sheet named Orders

// target sheet of move to named Archived

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var s = ss.getSheetByName("Orders");

var cellStart = s.getRange(2, 11);

var cellEnd = s.getRange(2, 12);

var rowStart = cellStart.getValue();

var numR = cellEnd.getValue() - cellStart.getValue() + 1;

var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archived");

var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

s.getRange(rowStart, 1, numR, 9).moveTo(target);

s.deleteRows(rowStart, numR);

}
```

Thanks everyone!